# Comparing a variable to a string using wildcards

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, wildcard, ksh

i am creating a script that reads each file in a certain directory and uses some info from each file, but there is a file called "logdia + date" in each directory which i dont want to include into my loop, i have tried tu use an if-statement to compare the rute of the file to a string using wildcards but the condition never fails, and it always includes the "logdia" file into my loop, what am i missing? Thankyou

```
list_dir=$(ls -tr /opt/srv001/app/sam/trazas/*$v_fecha*)

for dir in $list_dir
do
if [ $dir != "*logdia*" ]
 then
 //Do stuff
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way to do that is as follows:

```
for dir in /opt/srv001/app/sam/trazas/*$v_fecha*; do
   if [[ "$dir" != *"logdia"* ]]; then
      echo "Do stuff Here"
   fi
done
```

1. While comparing using glob patterns keep glob pattern outside quotes.
2. Avoid parsing ls's output.

Comment: Thankyou, i had tried using the wildcards outside the quotes and i had tried avoiding parsing its output, but not both things at the same time! Thanks again

Comment: Can you give a reason *why* should one avoid parsing ls's output?

Comment: @radlr: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Why one should not parse the output of ls (thanks to @anubhava for the link): 

One should not use ls because file names have no naming restrictions and this can mess up the ls command. E.g. if a file contains a newline character in its name ls might not work as expected.
So the best way to get all the file names in a directory is using the dir command.